# Prerequisites, using fetch(), html scripting

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, backend, fetch-api

I am trying to retrieve functions from my website's back-end which is primarily written in NodeJS, then use these values for the front-end/data bases. Achieving this looks like I need to use the fetch() function but I am not sure if that is a library I need to include or if it is integrated into the regular DOM environment. Are there any prerequisites to using the fetch() function within scripting tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only prerequisite is compatibility. Moderns browsers widely adopted Fetch API. If your application does not require include old browsers, feel safe to use. You can see more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in MDN.

Comment: Ok so just to be clear, I can ```<script> fetch(DirectorytoNodejs); var genKeys = new genKeyPair(); </script>```  where genKeyPair() is a function contained in that particular directory I specified?

Comment: No you can't ! `fetch` allows you make an HTTP request to your back-end service.